# Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_136_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 128, 128, 3)

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm training an CNN with LSTM, where I use TimeDistributed but apparently it wants an extra dimension for the data. I don't know how to add it. 
My thought is that the problem is in ImageGenerator, but I don't know how to reshape images generated from it.

```
cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,3)))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(16, 128, 128,3)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2)) #added
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
batch_size = 16


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train/',  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(128,128),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True,
        classes=['class_0', 'class_1','class_2','class_3'])

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'test/',
        target_size=(128,128),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True,
        classes=['class_0', 'class_1','class_2','class_3'])
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=47549 // batch_size,
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=5444 // batch_size)
```

But I'm getting the following error message

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_136_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 128, 128, 3)
```

Data folder is as follows:

```
 -- train
    -- class 0
       -- vid 1
          -- frame1.jpg
          -- frame2.jpg
          -- frame3.jpg
    -- class 1
          -- frame1.jpg
          -- frame2.jpg
          -- frame3.jpg
    -- class 2
    -- class 3
 -- test
   (same as train)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why you pass your input to TimeDistributed and not directly into the LSTM? Why define two sequential models while one is enough?

Comment: I  want to make a stacked CNN layers for video classification, and the two sequential models are not making a problem.

Comment: Why are you determine the input shape of your `TimeDistributed` as `input_shape=(16, 128, 128,3)` and not just `TimeDiinput_shape=(128, 128,3)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials, I ended up using the same code, but with a tweaked version of the Keras "ImageDataGenerator" Class to add an extra dimension to the data, so that it becomes 5D.
(This is also valid for the use of Conv3D)

For anyone who face the same problem, you can find my tweaked version of the ImageDataGenerator class [here](https://gist.github.com/Emadeldeen24/736c33ac2af0c00cc48810ad62e1f54a).

It's the same as the main Keras ImageDataGenerator but I added an option to take more than one image/frame on each iteration. This is by changing the parameter **frames_per_step** to specify the number of frames/images you want to include in each iteration.

So here's how to use it:

```
from tweaked_ImageGenerator_v2 import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_data=datagen.flow_from_directory('path/to/data', target_size=(x, y), batch_size=32, frames_per_step=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fogetting the first dimension of every tensor, which is the batch size. You don't define a batch size unless it's absolutely necessary, thus the input shapes don't consider it.

When you defined `input_shape=(16,128,128,3)`, this means that your data must have five dimensions: `(examples, 16, 128, 128, 3)`

And the examples dimension is missing in your data.

If you say they're movies, you should have data like `(movies, frames, height, width, channels)`, probably. Then this would be accepted by `input_shape=(frames, height, width, channels)`.

Comment: Thank you, I got your answer, but I didn't get how to solve the situation or what to change.

Comment: Does this mean to change the way data is organized?

Comment: What is 16 in your shape?

Comment: The number of frames for each batch

Comment: Ok, then everything is right, you just need more than one movie. (You provably have that)

Comment: yes, I do. This is really confusing!! 
Thanks anyway for your time and effort.

Comment: I edited the post to show how data is organized, please check and tell me if it is correct. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is with your `model`. You define the input shape of your `TimeDistributed` in your `model` as `input_shape=(16, 128, 128,3)` which I guess it should be `input_shape=(128, 128,3)`.

change this line :

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(16, 128, 128,3)))
```

to:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn_model, input_shape=(128, 128,3)))
```

And I hope it will work.

Comment: No this is not right.
Please check [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/)

Comment: Why? What is the problem?

Comment: My answer was exactly according to the documentation.

Comment: Here's the code from documentation:
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)),
                          input_shape=(10, 299, 299, 3)))
and yes I tried it, and it gives an error:

Comment: So can you post this new Error. Maybe your problem solved and now you are facing with new problem.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range